# strange behaviour with return/enter key in Brackets

Tags: autocomplete, user-interface, brackets

I'm learning web development, but Adobe Brackets' enter key behaviour is a little strange in my opinion. What happens is this:

I type `<html` like so:

[image]

then once I add the remaining `>`, it autocompletes the element

[image]

Then I'd press enter to do more coding within that element, but the element appears like this when I press enter, making me use the mouse to correct the cursor:

[image]

When the desired result is like this:

[image]

How can I achieve that? I've tried to search for plugins and key-combos, but I can't find anything.

Comment: What you are experiencing would seem to be expected behaviour? Or are you suggesting the edit window has lost focus (ie. no cursor) after hitting the enter key the first time? What platform are you on?

Comment: @w3d Changed the image now to better show the desired behaviour. if I type `<html>` and press enter, the closing tag moves down, and the cursor appears in front of the closing tag, instead of creating a new line in between the two like shown in the last image. At the moment, I need to move my cursor manually from the start of the closing tag, to the end of the opening tag to create a new line in between by tapping enter again from there. I'm on OS X El Capitan, but the behaviour is the same on my other computer with Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1):

This is no big deal, you're just overthinking it a bit. The solution is much simpler than you're realizing. Brackets is doing exactly what it's programmed to do in this situation. After it adds your closing tag just hit return once more then hit your up arrow once and then tab once. It will put the cursor exactly where you want it. You can then proceed to code normally.